# unresolved dependencies - Error while importing SBT project

Tags: sbt

Error while importing SBT project:
...

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-mapreduce-client-app;2.6.0-cdh5.4.2: not found
[warn]  :: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-mapreduce-client-core;2.6.0-cdh5.4.2: not found
[warn]  :: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient;2.6.0-cdh5.4.2: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last prj1/:update' for the full output.
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last prj2/:ssExtractDependencies' for the full output.
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last prj1/:ssExtractDependencies' for the full output.
[error] (prj1/:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-mapreduce-client-app;2.6.0-cdh5.4.2: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-mapreduce-client-core;2.6.0-cdh5.4.2: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient;2.6.0-cdh5.4.2: not found
[error] (prj2/:ssExtractDependencies) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-mapreduce-client-app;2.6.0-cdh5.4.2: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-mapreduce-client-core;2.6.0-cdh5.4.2: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient;2.6.0-cdh5.4.2: not found
[error] (prj1/:ssExtractDependencies) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-mapreduce-client-app;2.6.0-cdh5.4.2: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-mapreduce-client-core;2.6.0-cdh5.4.2: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient;2.6.0-cdh5.4.2: not found
[error] Total time: 146 s, completed May 17, 2016 4:16:57 PM
```

Any suggestions on how to go about resolving the issue. The import works fine on another machine.  I see the jar files in .ivy2 folder.

Comment: I will follow this here http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.1/docs/Detailed-Topics/Dependency-Management-Flow.html   and keep the updates to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using  Intellij, SBT. The issue was that the repositories location had to be properly specified. To specify that go to File -> Settings -> (Search for SBT) then in the VM parameters you can specify the repostories.

> -XX:MaxPermSize=1024M
>   -Dsbt.override.build.repos=true
>   -Dsbt.repository.config=/usr/local/basically_some_path/some_repo_file_name.repositories

IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.2
Build #IU-145.971, built on April 29, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_76-release-b47 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o