# Error while importing SBT project, even after making changes to VM ware parameters

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, virtual-machine

I am trying to import sbt and other dependencies in my IntelliJ and it fails with the below error.
I have tried the solutions given at [unresolved dependencies - Error while importing SBT project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37288051/unresolved-dependencies-error-while-importing-sbt-project)

but it does not work.

Below is the log of error:

Error while importing sbt project:

Java version: 1.7
VM ware : Latest Edition Licensed

```
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 1.2.1  (this may take some time)...
unresolved dependency: org.scala-sbt#sbt;1.2.1: not found
(see /home/cloudera/.sbt/boot/update.log for complete log)
Error: Could not retrieve sbt 1.2.1

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
module not found: org.scala-sbt#sbt;1.2.1

==== local: tried

/home/cloudera/.ivy2/local/org.scala-sbt/sbt/1.2.1/ivys/ivy.xml

-- artifact org.scala-sbt#sbt;1.2.1!sbt.jar:

/home/cloudera/.ivy2/local/org.scala-sbt/sbt/1.2.1/jars/sbt.jar

==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried

file:////home/cloudera/.sbt/preloaded/org.scala-sbt/sbt/1.2.1/ivys/ivy.xml

==== local-preloaded: tried

file:////home/cloudera/.sbt/preloaded/org/scala-sbt/sbt/1.2.1/sbt-1.2.1.pom

-- artifact org.scala-sbt#sbt;1.2.1!sbt.jar:

file:////home/cloudera/.sbt/preloaded/org/scala-sbt/sbt/1.2.1/sbt-1.2.1.jar

==== Maven Central: tried

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/1.2.1/sbt-1.2.1.pom

-- artifact org.scala-sbt#sbt;1.2.1!sbt.jar:

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/1.2.1/sbt-1.2.1.jar

==== sbt-maven-releases: tried

https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-releases/org/scala-sbt/sbt/1.2.1/sbt-1.2.1.pom

-- artifact org.scala-sbt#sbt;1.2.1!sbt.jar:

https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-releases/org/scala-sbt/sbt/1.2.1/sbt-1.2.1.jar

==== sbt-maven-snapshots: tried

https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-snapshots/org/scala-sbt/sbt/1.2.1/sbt-1.2.1.pom

-- artifact org.scala-sbt#sbt;1.2.1!sbt.jar:

https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-snapshots/org/scala-sbt/sbt/1.2.1/sbt-1.2.1.jar

==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried

https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/1.2.1/ivys/ivy.xml

==== sbt-ivy-snapshots: tried

https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/org.scala-sbt/sbt/1.2.1/ivys/ivy.xml

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:: org.scala-sbt#sbt;1.2.1: not found

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


:::: ERRORS
Server access Error: Received fatal alert: protocol_version url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/1.2.1/sbt-1.2.1.pom

Server access Error: Received fatal alert: protocol_version url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/1.2.1/sbt-1.2.1.jar

Server access Error: Connection reset url=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-releases/org/scala-sbt/sbt/1.2.1/sbt-1.2.1.pom

Server access Error: Connection reset url=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-releases/org/scala-sbt/sbt/1.2.1/sbt-1.2.1.jar

Server access Error: Connection reset url=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-snapshots/org/scala-sbt/sbt/1.2.1/sbt-1.2.1.pom

Server access Error: Connection reset url=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-snapshots/org/scala-sbt/sbt/1.2.1/sbt-1.2.1.jar

Server access Error: Connection reset url=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/1.2.1/ivys/ivy.xml

Server access Error: Connection reset url=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/org.scala-sbt/sbt/1.2.1/ivys/ivy.xml


:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
```

Comment: there is no need to make any changes to VM ware parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common issue with cloudera VM ware. The jdk version is 1.7 and scala 2.12 needs jdk version 1.8.

Download latest jdk and extract it on desktop. And when you open a new project for scala make sure your jdk is pointed to the latest one you downloaded.( by default it will use the jdk 1.7 which comes packged with cloudera VM ware.

Hopefully this helps.